# PostgreSQL: Students who took more than one test on the date of their most recent test

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL

Data:

```
Tests:  
- student (name, all unique)  
- date (MM/DD, assume same year)
```

Example:
Tests:

```
student  |  date
aa  |  01/01  
aa  |  01/01  
bb  |  01/01  
bb  |  01/02
```

Expected output:

```
student  |  date  
aa  | 01/01
```

Because bb only took 1 test; need to output students who took 2+ tests on same day for their most recent test date

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function on a column, it works on the whole selected rows!!! To make things clearer, skip those redundant parentheses, i.e. simply do `SELECT DISTINCT exams.student, exams.date`. However, your GROUP BY returns no duplicates, so you can just do SELECT here.

Comment: ahh TIL, thanks! yeah, I know that GROUP BY wouldn't have any direct effects, but I just used it to check the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that nowhere in your query can be found the part with the "most recent test".

So I took your query and added a subquery to find out this information for each student. Joining that with your query filters out every other test date and it works.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM exams e 

JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.student) 
        * 
    FROM exams e 
    ORDER BY e.student, e.date DESC
) s USING (student, date)

GROUP BY e.student, e.date
HAVING COUNT(e.date) >= 2  
ORDER BY e.student
```

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=452e92454511af28f10c0d1fe4e215e8)

Comment: Since I love the elegance of window functions in the solution of @TimBiegeleisen I would go for it because of its readability. But if your data set is really huge I would try the joining solution. This could be a little bit faster (cost difference: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6365497e06de8ade5706dddc0250bfcd)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, using analytic functions:

```
SELECT student, date
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY student ORDER BY date DESC) rn,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY student, date) cnt
    FROM exams
) t
WHERE rn = 1 AND cnt > 1;
```

### Demo

Comment: I think the OP also wants the date in the results?  Also, I think as worded your query doesn't need DISTINCT?

Comment: @MatBailie Can't believe we almost posted the same answer.  We must be drinking the same Kool-Aid.

Comment: But, with me on my new split keyboard, you type much faster :)

Comment: You're right about not needing `DISTINCT`.  I was thinking backwards that I had used `RANK`, and therefore there would be multiple ties.  With `ROW_NUMBER`, we're picking an arbitrary "first" row, but it doesn't matter which one.